# Eigen Linear Algebra library is too slow

Tags: eigen

I have a positive definite matrix and I want to use Cholesky to solve it.  I use Eigen and do this:

```
VectorXd x1 =A1.ldlt().solve(B1);  //35.7ms
```

Over 100 runs, the average is 35.7ms.  Is this normal?  My own code can execute in 10ms, using Red Hat and a Intel i7-3770 3.4 GHz.

How can I speed it up?  The matrix size is 241x241 and the vector 241.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you enabled compiler's optimizations. For instance, for gcc or clang you might use:

```
-O2 -msse2 -DNDEBUG
```

For such a matrix size Eigen's take 0.8ms on a core i7 @ 2.6 GHz.

Comment: Yes, that speeds it up.  I tried on my ARM Cortex A9 and it took 40ms.  But my code also took 40ms.  I was under the impression it was meant to be super quick.  Or my code is super quick.  On my Intel both registered as 0ms.  I used 03 and 02 optimization, no difference.  I will need to think, if I will use this.

Comment: Also EIGEN_NO_DEBUG=1

Comment: Not really because, `-DNDEBUG` implies `EIGEN_NO_DEBUG=1`